# Error when working with HTML canvas - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have written a code for a game based on a html canvas. When I run it, I do not get the canvas game loaded onto the canvas. Instead I get the below error in my console:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

I have given my code below. Can someone please explain me what might be the reason?

```js
<script>

 var context;
    var canvas;
 var ctx;
 var speed = urlParam('speed');
    if (speed == null)
        speed = 40
    $('#speed').val(speed);
 calculateBubble(parseInt(speed));
 
    var redSBLatter;
    var redSBFormer;

    var redSBWindowFormer;
    var redSBWindowLatter;

    var blueSB;

    var blueSWindow;


    function startGame(bubbleLength, windowLength) {
        redSBWindowFormer = new slidingWindow(60, windowLength * 2, "black", 5, 120);
        redSBWindowLatter = new slidingWindow(60, 40, "black", 5, 80);
        redSBFormer = new component(30, bubbleLength, "red", 20, 120);
        redSBLatter = new component(30, 30, "red", 20, 90);

        blueSWindow = new slidingWindow(60, 70, "black", 120, 10);
        blueSB = new component(20, 40, "blue", 140, 20);
        myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
        start: function () {
   canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   //myCanvas.width = "480";
            //myCanvas.height = "480";

            document.body.insertBefore(canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
        clear: function () {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
    }
 
 function urlParam(name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (results == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
        }
    }




    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function () {
   ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
        this.newPos = function () {
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY;
        }
    }

    function slidingWindow(width, height, color, x, y) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function () {
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.beginPath();
   //ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
            ctx.lineWidth = "3";
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        this.newPos = function () {
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY;
        }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        myGameArea.clear();
        redSBLatter.newPos();
        redSBLatter.update();
        redSBFormer.newPos();
        redSBFormer.update();
        redSBWindowLatter.newPos();
        redSBWindowLatter.update();
        redSBWindowFormer.newPos();
        redSBWindowFormer.update();
        blueSB.newPos();
        blueSB.update();
        blueSWindow.newPos();
        blueSWindow.update();
    }

    function redmoveup() {
        redSBLatter.speedY = -1;
        redSBFormer.speedY = -1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedY = -1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedY = -1;

    }

    function bluemoveup() {
        blueSB.speedY = -1;
        blueSWindow.speedY = -1;
    }

    function redmovedown() {
        redSBLatter.speedY = 1;
        redSBFormer.speedY = 1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedY = 1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedY = 1;
    }

    function bluemovedown() {
        blueSB.speedY = 1;
        blueSWindow.speedY = 1;
    }

    function redmoveleft() {
        redSBLatter.speedX = -1;
        redSBFormer.speedX = -1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedX = -1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedX = -1;
    }

    function bluemoveleft() {
        blueSB.speedX = -1;
        blueSWindow.speedX = -1;
    }

    function redmoveright() {
        redSBLatter.speedX = 1;
        redSBFormer.speedX = 1;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedX = 1;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedX = 1;
    }

    function bluemoveright() {
        blueSB.speedX = 1;
        blueSWindow.speedX = 1;
    }

    function clearmove() {
        redSBLatter.speedX = 0;
        redSBLatter.speedY = 0;
        redSBFormer.speedX = 0;
        redSBFormer.speedY = 0;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedX = 0;
        redSBWindowLatter.speedY = 0;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedX = 0;
        redSBWindowFormer.speedY = 0;
        blueSB.speedX = 0;
        blueSB.speedY = 0;
        blueSWindow.speedX = 0;
        blueSWindow.speedY = 0;
    }

/**    function calculateBubble() {
        var kmh = document.getElementById("speed").value;
        if (kmh <= 0) {
            var bubble = 5.84;
            var window = bubble * 5;
            document.getElementById("bubble").innerHTML = bubble;
            document.getElementById("window").innerHTML = window;
            return startGame(20, 20);
        }
        else {
            //var v = getMph(kmh);
            var v = kmh / 1.6093;
            var feet = 2.2 * v + ((v * v) / 20);
            var bubblemeters = feet / 3.28;
            var bubble = parseFloat(bubblemeters.toFixed(2));

            document.getElementById("bubble").innerHTML = bubble;

            calculateWindow(bubble);

            return bubblemeters;
        }
    }**/
 
 function calculateBubble(kmh) {
        var v = kmh / 1.6093;
        var feet = 2.2 * v + ((v * v) / 20)
        var meters = feet / 3.28;
        $('#sBubble').empty();
        $('#sBubble').append("Safety bubble : " + meters.toFixed(2) + " m");
  calculateWindow(meters);
    }

    function calculateWindow(bubble) {

        var windowMeters = bubble + 5;
        var window = parseFloat(windowMeters.toFixed());

        document.getElementById("window").innerHTML = window;
        startGame(bubble, window);

    }

</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
        #canvas {
            border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
            background-color: #2196F3;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .grid-item {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Staging Area Simulation</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="public_html/jquery.js"></script>
    
</head>
<!--<body onload="startGame()">-->

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
  <div>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="480">
            </canvas>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3>Enter Parameters</h3>
            <p id="sBubble">Safety bubble : 0.0 m</p>
            Sliding Window :<p id="window"></p>
            <form method="get" id="form">
                speed : <input type="text" id="speed" name="speed" /> <br /><br />
                Vehicle Length : <input type="text" id="vLength" name="vLength" value="3.84m" disabled />
                <br /><br />
                Vehicle Width : <input type="text" id="vWidth" name="vWidth" value="1.74m" disabled />
                <br /><br />
                <button name="data" type="submit">Calculate</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
            <h3>
                Red Controllers </h3>
                    <button onmousedown="redmoveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()">UP</button><br><br>
                    <button onmousedown="redmoveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()">LEFT</button>
                    <button onmousedown="redmoveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
                    <button onmousedown="redmovedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()">DOWN</button>
        </div>

        <div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
            <h3> Blue Controllers</h3>
            <button onmousedown="bluemoveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()">UP</button><br><br>
            <button onmousedown="bluemoveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()">LEFT</button>
            <button onmousedown="bluemoveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
            <button onmousedown="bluemovedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()">DOWN</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you add this function also `decodeURI`